# persistent storage in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

how we can fetch images from persistent storage of blackberry?

Answer (score 2):

First of course you have to store the images there. I suggest you review some RIM documentation on the subject. This [article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800625/How_To_-_Store_persistent_data_on_the_BlackBerry_smartphone.html?nodeid=800530&vernum=0) is a good place to start. And it is good to know where the [knowledge base](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/customview.html?func=ll&objId=348583) is. There are also [Developer videos](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/videolibrary.jsp#tab_ddetail_subtab_jde) which include one on the [persistence model](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=Persistence%20Models).